# Trying to bundle dependencies with jar

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am attempting to create a maven config for a small utility set that will jar the utilities as well as their dependent jars (just one in this case so far).  I have read through the stuff on uberjars, shade, assemblies, etc.  But, I cannot get the dependent jars to bundle in the main jar.  I am fairly new to maven and have never needed to bundle dependent jars like this.  I have a config that will run and produce a jar but I cannot get the dependency-jars to show up in target, as I am assuming they should?  So, I figure I am either close and maybe have a tweak or something to make.  Or, I am just completely off, which could be the case too.

Here is the current config:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
<artifactId>RejectFileProcessor</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>RejectFileProcessor</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <srcDir>src</srcDir>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${srcDir}</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.dst.reject.RejectFileCleaner</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/uberJar.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.dst.reject.RejectFileCleaner</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.apache.commons</includeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

There is still an assembly plugin in there, but it is commented out.  That did not work for me either.  The build will run and produce a build, but never appears to hit the stuff for dependencies.

Any ideas on what I am missing or screwing up?

Answer (score 0):

Most important reason: you've put the `maven-dependency-plugin` within the pluginManagement tags. In simple words: plugins within pluginManagement are preconfigured plugins, and are only used if they are explicitly called. This works for the maven-compiler-plugin and maven-jar-plugin, because these plugin are already bound to the default buildlifecycle for jars (done by Maven). If you move the maven-dependency-plugin to `<project><build><plugins>` then it will picked up when calling `mvn package`.

Comment: +1 Robert thanks.  I originally did not have the plugin management in there because I did not think I needed it, but without it the dependency-plugin gives me the following:

**maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e.**

Comment: That's just a warning saying the integration of this plugin with Eclipse is not optimal. And I would suggest to use the maven-shade-plugin instead, which is the strongest plugin for this purpose. Again: don't put it under pluginManagement.